# Remove ViewPager2 Overscroll animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

Can't find a way to remove the ViewPager2 overscroll shadow animation.
I know on ViewPager, you can directly just set the overscrollMode attribute to never, however, it does not work on ViewPager2

Already tried the following

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"/>
```

```
binding.viewPager.apply {
        adapter = adapter
        orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL
        overScrollMode = ViewPager2.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
        offscreenPageLimit = if (containsVideo) 2 else 5
}
```

Comment: ViewPager2 probably isn't forwarding the overScrollMode to the RecyclerView it uses internally. Can you [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=561920)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Filed it right over, thank you

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134912610

Comment: Just wasted a lot of time on this petty issue, this question and its answers deserve more visibility!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Solution

```
binding.viewPager2.apply {
    adapter = vpAdapter
    orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL
    registerOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback)
    (getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView).overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
}
```

Comment: Please provide solution without data binding

Comment: @galaxigirl 
`findViewById(R.id.viewPagerIdFromLayout).apply {
    (getChildAt(0) as? RecyclerView)?.overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
}`

Comment: Not sure about when this answer was originally written, but currently `overScrollMode` and `OVER_SCROLL_NEVER` are functions/constants on `View`, not `RecyclerView`. So the answer reduces to `fun ViewPager2.disableOverscroll() {getChildAt(0).overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER}`

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone searching for a Java solution

```
View child = viewPager2.getChildAt(0);
if (child instanceof RecyclerView) {
    child.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Kotlin extension:

```
fun ViewPager2.removeOverScroll() {
    (getChildAt(0) as? RecyclerView)?.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
}
```

and you are using it in your Fragment/Activity:

```
viewPager.removeOverScroll()
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can simply do it like this

`viewpager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);`

Comment: What if the child referenced using `.getChildAt(0)` is not present in the Recycle View? It will throw an exception. The current code doesn't handles that case. Please [edit] to handle such case.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
val child = binding.<your viewPager camelCase id>.getChildAt(0)
    (child as? RecyclerView)?.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
```

Answer (score 0):

My kotlin code version that work in my project, without binding:

```
// over scroll animation
val child: View = pager.getChildAt(0)

if (child is RecyclerView) {
    child.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use             android:overScrollMode="never"

```
 <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/infoViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideLine1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />
```