# Disable overglow effect in ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

Can not remove the glow effect on over-scroll in `TabLayout` with `ViewPager2`.

I have tried `android:overScrollMode="never"` and `android:fadingEdge="none"` but it doesn't work.

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `android:overScrollMode="never"` is not disabling the over scroll effect.
The respective issue created on the issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134912610

But you can try workaround, described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61078024/16210149) answer.

Comment: The issue was created over one year ago and still isn't fixed...

Comment: @MoisoniIoan 2023 still not fixed :D

Answer (score 0):

As @Anatolii Chub mentioned, it is an issue. He provided a link to a workaround in `Kotlin` but I use `Java` in my project so this is the solution:

```
//disable glow effect when over-scroll
if (viewPager2.getChildAt(0) instanceof RecyclerView) {
    viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}
```

His answer will remain accepted because he provided info for solution.